# Two way data binding is not working in directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I'm fairly new to AngularJS and it's the first time I'm writing a directive.

I'm trying to make [Bootstrap Year Calendar](http://bootstrap-year-calendar.com/) work with AngularJS. It is a jQuery plug-in to show a calendar with appointments.

I've written this directive to create the calendar:

```
    app.directive('calendarScheduler', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                calendarData: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                element.calendar({
                    enableRangeSelection: true,
                    dataSource: scope.calendarData
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

The data is passed to the directive from this controller:

```
var app = angular.module('App', [])

app.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', 
    function($scope) {
        $scope.User = {};
        $scope.User.eventsData = [];

        init();

        $scope.User.addData = function(startDate, endDate) {
            $scope.User.eventsData.push({
                id: 2,
                name: 'Apple Special Event',
                location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                startDate: new Date(2016, 6, 28),
                endDate: new Date(2016, 6, 29)
            });
        };

        function init() {
            $scope.User.eventsData = [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: 'Google I/O',
                    location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                    startDate: new Date(2016, 4, 28),
                    endDate: new Date(2016, 4, 29)
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Microsoft Convergence',
                    location: 'New Orleans, LA',
                    startDate: new Date(2016, 2, 16),
                    endDate: new Date(2016, 2, 19)
                }
            ];
        }
     }]);
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<body ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
        <div
            calendar-scheduler
            id="calendar" 
            class="calendar" 
            calendar-data="User.eventsData">
        </div>
        <button data-ng-click="UserHoliday.addData();">Add Data</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Plunker showing the result](https://plnkr.co/edit/RftFghl0KqkgnO9HmgSZ?p=preview)

Everything works if the data is passed at the creation of the directive, but if I click the button to add more data to the calendar, it does not update the data shown (It should show one new appointment). This also does not show data loaded using $http.
I've tried $scope.$apply() to update the $scope, both on controller and directive, but it throws an error "$apply already in progress".

As I've said, I'm really new to AngularJS, and I don't know how to make this work, or if I'm missing something here.

Hope you can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only bind the data once, so it will never update. Instead 'watch' the data collection:

```
app.directive('calendarScheduler', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            calendarData: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            function init() {
                element.calendar({
                    enableRangeSelection: true,
                    dataSource: scope.calendarData
                });
            }

            // re-init when data is changed
            scope.$watchCollection("calendarData", function(val) {
                // according to the documentation, data can be updated by doing:
                element.data("calendar").setDataSource(val);
            });

            init();

            scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
                // not sure if this is supported by the library,
                // but is a best practice to prevent memory leaks
                element.calendar("destroy");
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: the `ngModel` directive isn't necesarry in itself in that case, what is important is to inform angular that the scope changed through scope.$apply since jQUery events happen outside of angular.

Comment: Yeah I read it wrong first, I thought it would be an input :)

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you very much!!
I used a $watch but it did just update the data once (don't know why), didn't know about $watchCollection.

Comment: Answering to myself. 
$watch() just checks to see if the new and old values are the same "physical" object, while $watchCollection() goes one-level deep and performs an additional, shallow reference check of the top level items in the collection.

Seen [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm)